# Changing the refractive index of a specific medium using radio frequency (RF) waves

Tags: electromagnetism, doppler-effect, radio-frequency

Using Ultrasound one can change the refractive index of a specific medium such as biological tissue, I was wondering if it is possible to change the refractive index of a medium such as biological tissue using Radio Frequency (RF) waves.

Changing the refractive index of a specific medium then allows frequency-tagged light emissions from a known location via a mechanical Doppler shift of the emitter (Mahan et al., 1998)

Comment: Yes. Just as the first one is behind acousto-optic modulators, the second one is behind electro-optic modulators. Hopefully that's enough to kick-start your search?

Comment: Perfect, thanks I will look into that now. Do you have any specific papers or use cases where this has been demonstrated especially in biological tissue?

Comment: Or to alter my question, does there need to be specific conditions of the medium that are needed to change the refractive index which differ from changing the refractive index using Ultrasound

Comment: I don't know of any uses in biological tissue. There could well be fundamental roadblocks with that class of materials, for all I know. But the overall principle is valid.

Comment: Okay that sounds great, thanks for your help!